# An over- and under-voltage protection system

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, switches, timer, 555

How can the block diagram below operate as an over and under voltage protection system?

I thought it will work as follows:

A step-down transformer is used to bring down the alternating current supply to 12 volts. The bridge rectifier converts the alternating current supply to a direct current supply. To decrease harmonics, the supply is subsequently filtered by capacitors connected across the rectifier.

The unregulated supply is then routed through a voltage regulator, the output of which is fed to two distinct 555 timers. One 555 timer will be utilized for overvoltage detection, while the other 555 timer will be used for under voltage detection.

When an over/low voltage is detected, a trip signal is sent to the relay, causing the circuit to open and the lamp to be protected. When no over/under voltage detected in a 555 timer, the circuit will continue to run correctly.

[image: Block diagram]

[image: Circuit diagram, found on the link, https://media.cheggcdn.com/coop/80c/80cb9aa8-dfe9-49dd-822e-c2a5fb344a65/1651246306252_blob]

Comment: Welcome! It’s only a guess from the block diagram (simplified). Something more is happening between the relay and the lamp. But you can sense the rectified voltage and choose not to activate the relay depending on predetermined voltage levels. Can you perhaps expand your question? Do you have a schematic?

Comment: Please provide a link to where you found that image, for context (and because it's a rule).

Comment: The 555's in your system are almost certainly *not* being used as timers, so it's probably confusing you and others to refer to them as "555 timers". There are many "off-label" uses of the ubiquitous 555 where its pair of internal comparators and SR-latch make it great for other purposes.

Comment: Very good! Strange choice to use a 555 as a comparator here but you effectively have a window comparator.

Answer (score 3):

The 555 timer IC contains a comparator (two, actually) so it's possible to coax it into acting as a under/over voltage detector if you power it from a regulated (reference) voltage. Here is one circuit (from [here](https://www.elprocus.com/under-and-overvoltage-protection-circuit/)) that is claimed to perform that function. I have not attempted to evaluate it, looks a bit dodgy.

[image]

NE555 innards, from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC):

[image]

Comment: May you kindly post back the picture of the circuit, it dissapered

Comment: Everything I put there is still there. Maybe you need to refresh the page.